# Fabcar Tutorial - Error: error sending transaction for invoke: could not send: EOF

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to launch the sample Fabcar tutorial network using the command "./startFabric.sh javascript" but unfortunately getting the below error at the last step while submitting initLedger transaction to smart contract on mychannel.

So when I query the ledger, it doesn't return anything.
can somebody advise whats wrong with my test network? Kindly let me know if you need additional details.

**Error: error sending transaction for invoke: could not send: EOF - proposal response: version:1 response: payload:"\n** \242tu\327\261\372F\2679&\205\027\010\255\323\025]\300~\273`\202\316\031zx\316\237\035\333\364\022\356\007\n\327\007\0227\n\n_lifecycle\022)\n'\n!namespaces/fields/fabcar/Sequence\022\002\010\005\022\233\007\n\006fabcar\022\220\007\032Y\n\004CAR0\032Q{"color":"blue","make":"Toyota","model":"Prius","owner":"Tomoko","docType":"car"}\032V\n\004CAR1\032N{"color":"red","make":"Ford","model":"Mustang","owner":"Brad","docType":"car"}\032]\n\004CAR2\032U{"color":"green","make":"Hyundai","model":"Tucson","owner":"Jin Soo","docType":"car"}\032]\n\004CAR3\032U{"color":"yellow","make":"Volkswagen","model":"Passat","owner":"Max","docType":"car"}\032V\n\004CAR4\032N{"color":"black","make":"Tesla","model":"S","owner":"Adriana","docType":"car"}\032Z\n\004CAR5\032R{"color":"purple","make":"Peugeot","model":"205","owner":"Michel","docType":"car"}\032W\n\004CAR6\032O{"color":"white","make":"Chery","model":"S22L","owner":"Aarav","docType":"car"}\032W\n\004CAR7\032O{"color":"violet","make":"Fiat","model":"Punto","owner":"Pari","docType":"car"}\032Y\n\004CAR8\032Q{"color":"indigo","make":"Tata","model":"Nano","owner":"Valeria","docType":"car"}\032\n\004CAR9\032T{"color":"brown","make":"Holden","model":"Barina","owner":"Shotaro","docType":"car"}\032\003\010\310\001"\r\022\006fabcar\032\0031.0" e

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. I had downloaded the fabric samples twice on my PC which might have caused the issue. I deleted everything and downloaded the samples again before trying again and it worked!!